# Comparison of DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame of comparison result, from that I need to get a index of row where all column values are false. Please Help me to move on.

[image]]

Answer (score 0):

Compare for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with test if `True`s  per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `axis=1` and filter indices in `df1` like:

```
idx = df1.index[df1.ne(df2).all(axis=1)]
```